# Which topology is correct for segmentation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have an image size of `WxHx3` that needs to segment into 21 classes. After passing through some layers using CNN, I obtained the `W/4 x H/4 x 512` feature maps. We will use a `Convolutional` and `Deconvolutional` layer finally to compare it with its label in `softmax` layer. I have 2 topologies:

```
  Softmax_loss                                  Softmax_loss
       ^                                             ^
       |                                             |
  deconv_layer                                   conv_layer
       ^                                             ^
       |                                             |
    conv_layer                                  deconv_layer
       ^                                             ^
       |                                             |
Intermediate_layers                         Intermediate_layers
       ^                                             ^
       |                                             |
     Input                                         Input

      (1)                                           (2)
```

Which topology is better? I have seen both of them. No.1 in `FCN` (fully convolution network for semantic segmentation), No.2 in `VoxResNet`, `UNet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no correct way in deep learning. You usually try things and which ever works best for you. If you follow `fcn` model it starts like `conv->deconv->conv->deconv`. Most cited papers in semantic segmentation do `conv->deconv`. So I would suggest No. 1 too. Also intuitively, doing `deconv` first doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes. The FCN uses `conv(1x1,classifier)->deconv`. However, some paper also use `deconv->conv(1x1)` like Unet, VoxResNet papers. So I think they have some reason for that

Comment: @KimHee are you sure Unet, VoxResNet do `deconv` first? I saw their prototxt file and they do `conv` first. If you are talking about what to do last then I think it matters on what works best.

Comment: And Unet is conv_u0d-sc is classifier at lass prototxt. https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/resources/opensource/3dUnet_miccai2016_no_BN.prototxt . I means the before softmax layer process

Comment: @KimHee I meant `conv` first as in first layer. As I already said in case of just before `loss` it matters on whatever works best for you.